# Предложения по улучшению системы оценок на форуме

Tags: общие-вопросы

Хотелось бы в открытой форме обсудить существующие оценки и предложить новые:

1) Ответ полезен – 10 баллов

2) Ответ не является полезным (отступление от темы, очевидное нарушение общепринятых грамматических или орфографических правил и т.д.) – 2 балла. 
Нежелательно  отмечать этим знаком  тот ответ, который просто не совпадает с вашим мнением.

3) Автор удовлетворен этим ответом – 10 баллов (не больше)
Автор вопроса не должен определять ответ как правильный или лучший. Правильность/неправильность ответа следует из общего мнения сообщества. Автор же отмечает только тот факт, что ответ ему понятен и лично для него полезен.
Это позволит избежать ситуаций, когда автор вопроса вынужден считать себя ответственным за правильность ответа, и тогда он начинает менять свои решения.

4) Также желательно определить срок, в течение которого делается авторская отметка, например: от 48 до 120 часов. Затем отметку сделает не автор, а модератор.

5) И еще вопрос: можно ли определить, как голосует каждый участник? Думаю, что эти сведения должны быть открытыми. Понятно, что голос участника с репутацией более важен, чем голос новичка.

Comment: Для обсуждения принципов работы сайта есть специальный форум [Мета](http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) Ответ полезен – 10 баллов
> >
> > 2) Ответ не является полезным (отступление от темы, очевидное нарушение общепринятых грамматических или орфографических правил и т.д.) – 2 балла.

И получится, что пять двоек эквивалентны одной десятке?

Comment: Это прежние расценки, но вообще говоря, и на других форумах поощрительные оценки всегда выше отрицательных. Но меня больше интересует следующее. Не надо очень быстро принимать ответы и нельзя их вообще не принимать. Не надо называть принятый автором ответ абсолютной истиной. Голосование должно быть ответственным и отражать объективные заслуги или промахи участников.

Answer (score 0):

Хотел сделать комментарием, но понял, что это на ответ тянет...

Насколько понимаю, быстрое "принятие" ответа отвечает политике ресурса. Причины мне не совсем понятны (или не совсем известны), но в основном можно согласиться, что нахождение зрительной отметки для одного правильного ответа способствует восприятию человека, пришедшего за ответом, а не за разговорами. А именно на таких и ориентирован ресурс - популярность добавляют тысячи читателей, а не десятки писателей. Беда, правда, в том, что на "гуманитарном" форуме нет критерия для абсолютно правильного ответа, который зачастую без обсуждения и найти-то невозможно...

Comment: Но вот форум "Большой вопрос" вообще коммерческий, но там дается обязательная выдержка, потом автору предлагают принять ответ, в противном случае принимают сами. А так получается, что многие не успевают даже прочитать вопрос, а он уже принят. Отсюда и не лучшее качество ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Может, оценивать по 5-балльной шкале? Только оценивать *каждый* полученный ответ.